# Counting all items linked to foreign key

Tags: django, django-views

I'm looking for a solution to combine in one view information from two models.
One model is for "node" definition. Second model is "drive" definition, where I have foreign key for "node". One "node" can contain many drives.
In a template I need to show all assigned drives for a given node in a list view. I'm interested in count, a number of drives assigned to given node.

I don't have any new idea how calculate this information and pass to template. Should I count this as a "pure python"? I believe there is a way in Django as this doesn't look very complex.

View:

```
class NodeListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'nodes/nodes_list.html'
    queryset = Node.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'nodes'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        drives = Drive.objects.all()
        context.update({
            'drives': drives
        })
        return context
```

Models:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    .... more ....

class Drive(models.Model):
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='nodes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .... more ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the `Node`s with the number of related `Drive`s:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class NodeListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'nodes/nodes_list.html'
    queryset = Node.objects.annotate(ndrives=Count('nodes'))
    context_object_name = 'nodes'
```

then you can render this with:

```
{% for node in nodes %}
    {{ node.ndrives }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can also enumerate over the *related* `Drive`s with:

```
{% for node in nodes %}
    {{ node.ndrives }}
    {% for drive in node.nodes.all %}
        {{ drive }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

where you can boost efficiency with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class NodeListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'nodes/nodes_list.html'
    queryset = Node.objects.annotate(
        ndrives=Count('nodes')
    ).prefetch_related('nodes')
    context_object_name = 'nodes'
```

The reason that this is named `nodes` is because of the `related_name='nodes'`. This however does not make much sense: `related_name='drives'` would make more sense, since this deals with a collection of `Drive`s, you thus might want to rename this to:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    # …

class Drive(models.Model):
    node = models.ForeignKey(
        Node,
        related_name='drives',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

Then the view thus looks like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class NodeListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'nodes/nodes_list.html'
    queryset = Node.objects.annotate(
        ndrives=Count('drives')
    ).prefetch_related('drives')
    context_object_name = 'nodes'
```

and we render this with:

```
{% for node in nodes %}
    {{ node.ndrives }}
    {% for drive in node.drives.all %}
        {{ drive }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```